# Formula help and guidance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Click image to enlarge
[image: IMG:]

So as you can see this is pretty much a work in progress and when I change one formula it effects something else. So my main concerns are the following:

1. I would like to enter my new data at the top of the sheet not the bottom as I fill the rows is this possible. I was thinking maybe a macro to reverse the order
2. I have highlighted 4 cells pink and I am going to reference 4 here. What I want to do is this  (please bear with me as it is long) If C5 = XYZ then max lot is 200, if C5 = ABC then max lot size is 50 and if C5 = MNO max lot size is 250. This is the formula I have in X5 at the moment which does half of what I want:

```
=IF(ROUNDDOWN(AF5/$O$5,1)/10>$Q$3,$Q$3,ROUNDDOWN(AF5/$O$5,1)/10)
```

3. My #Name error is coming from blank cells in the columns prior. The last change I did was this which caused the error

```
=IFS(C5="XAUUSD",Variables!$E$44,C5="AUDJPY",Variables!$E$7,C5="AS200",Variables!$E$4,C5="AUDCAD",Variables!$E$5,C5="AUDCHF",Variables!$E$6,C5="AUDNZD",Variables!$E$8,C5="AUDUSD",Variables!$E$9,C5="CADCHF",Variables!$E$10,C5="CADJPY",Variables!$E$11,C5="CHFJPY",Variables!$E$12,C5="CN50",Variables!$E$13,C5="EURAUD",Variables!$E$14,C5="EURCAD",Variables!$E$15,C5="EURCHF",Variables!$E$16,C5="EURJPY",Variables!$E$17,C5="EURNZD",Variables!$E$18,C5="EURUSD",Variables!$E$19,C5="FRA40",Variables!$E$20,C5="GBPAUD",Variables!$E$21,C5="GBPCAD",Variables!$E$22,C5="GBPCHF",Variables!$E$23,C5="GBPJPY",Variables!$E$24,C5="GBPNZD",Variables!$E$25,C5="GBPUSD",Variables!$E$26,C5="GER30",Variables!$E$27,C5="HK50",Variables!$E$28,C5="IT40",Variables!$E$29,C5="JPN225",Variables!$E$30,C5="NAS100",Variables!$E$31,C5="NZDCAD",Variables!$E$32,C5="NZDCHF",Variables!$E$33,C5="NZDJPY",Variables!$E$34,C5="NZDUSD",Variables!$E$35,C5="SPA35",Variables!$E$36,C5="UK100",Variables!$E$37,C5="US2000",Variables!$E$38,C5="US30",Variables!$E$39,C5="US500",Variables!$E$40,C5="USDCAD",Variables!$E$41,C5="USDCHF",Variables!$E$42,C5="USDJPY",Variables!$E$43,C5="XTIUSD",Variables!$E$45,TRUE," ")
```

I believe it is my True line that caused it but then it makes other cells go out of sync.

That is where I am at at the moment and I have a few more things I will want to amend but I am not sure if I need the full picture first or can I amend along the way. Would also like to understand what I am doing so I am not in this position again.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Hi Kelly, what does your variables page look like. Is there a reason you cannot use a vlookup or index/match combo formula rather than all those if statements? In the D column of variables just put the values you want to match then change the formula to: =VLOOKUP(C5,Variables!$D$1:$E$45,2).

Comment: @JustinDoward the VLOOKUP is an option but I have never used it or understood it so I possible have a lot of redundant coding in my formulas. My Variables page is simple it is merely housing the data like price, asset, long/short, time frame and description of strategy. I have data validation on some of my fields in my main spreadsheet

Comment: I am not sure if that means you are going to change the formula or not? VLOOKUP simply looks up a value in a table, then returns a value from the matched row and from the identified column. So if the table starts in column D and you have 2 to identify the column, it returns the value in the matched E column (as in the example in my last comment).

Comment: @JustinDoward I will try it now I have been reading more about Vlookups this afternoon

Comment: @JustinDoward thanks I have changed it to the lookup table to reduce the formulas and added a if error blank field in my #name column. So I am now stuck on points 1 and 2